# How do I unhide child elements after the parent has been hidden?

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure what I need here but I am working on filtering results. Within the content div are the rows I am filtering. This is just one of the rows. When I hide .m-music, JQuery hides all of the child elements as well. When I want to show everything, I thought I could just do:

```
$("div.content div.m-music".show();
```

and have it show all its children, but that's not what's happening. It will only unhide the `.m-music` div. How can I show everything? Do I need a loop?

```
  <div class="content">
    <div class="m-music">  <----------------This and below should be unhidden
      <div class="tas"></div>
      <div class="data-row">
        <div class="info">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>this should be unhidden</td>
                <td>this should be unhidden</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div>this should be unhidden</div>
        </div>
        <div class="user-post">
          this should be unhidden
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

So, I can see from the snippet that was posted below that only the parent is being hidden. I think I know why now after looking at the JQuery.

```
$("div.content div").hide(); //hide all
```

Is it because this `div.content div` is recursively setting *all* the divs to hidden? If so, how do I only hide the parent?

Comment: It's not possible. If a parent is hidden, all its contents are hidden.

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery, it's the way the `display: none;` CSS style works.

Comment: Instead of hiding the parent, hide all the children. Then unhide the ones you want to see.

Comment: .show will only show the selected element(s). It will not recursively show everything below it. for that functionality, one would need to increase the collection of selected elements to include those others that you wish to show.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. I think Barmar is right, there is something else going wrong in my code. I'm not real good with javascript so I'll have to post more of this code.

Comment: check m-music, data-row and info classes. One of them might be setting height of the div and setting overflow to hidden.

Comment: Good thinking, Manpreet, I'll look now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you hide a class, it is given a `style="display:none;"` attribute and any children elements are hidden, but none of them are given this attribute so when you show that class again, the children elements will become visible again.

So if that's not happening in your code I suggest that there might be another problem somewhere.

I made a snippet to demonstrate this hiding and showing on a loop.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $("div.content div.m-music").hide();
}, 2000)
setTimeout(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $("div.content div.m-music").show();
  }, 2000)
}, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="m-music">
    <div class="tas"></div>
    <div class="data-row">
      <div class="info">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>this should be unhidden</td>
              <td>this should be unhidden</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <div>this should be unhidden</div>
      </div>
      <div class="user-post">
        this should be unhidden
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Brendon. I'm not sure what's happening in my code but I'll be updating the question with more code. Thank you for this...

Comment: Possibly there's something wrong with the html? Check all your closing tags have `/`

Comment: Brendan, yes, they are all closed. Look at this though... Could this be why all of the divs are being hidden? `$("div.content div").hide();`

Comment: Yes, that will hide all of the divs, you would need to have the same selector in the show call to work correctly, but you want to target div.m-music right?

Comment: Brendan, that was it. All I had to do was modify `div.content div` to be more specific and now I can target only the first div. None of the others are hidden as your code snippet proves. Thank you for showing that!